# RecyclerView displaying wrong data in other positions

Tags: android, json, android-studio, listview, android-recyclerview

I am creating a RecyclerView with Card view 
my json data contains movie name,year,rating 
my card view contains three text fields moviename,rating,year
when i click on rating field it should get the data from the json and display rating beside the rating text field, but the problem here is when i click on text field the data of my card view is displayed on other positions of the card view also.

```java
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    mList = findViewById(R.id.recylcerview);
    movieList = new ArrayList<>();
    builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    adapter = new MovieAdapter(this, movieList);
    linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
    dividerItemDecoration = new DividerItemDecoration(mList.getContext(), linearLayoutManager.getOrientation());
    mList.setHasFixedSize(true);
    mList.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
    mList.addItemDecoration(dividerItemDecoration);
    mList.setAdapter(adapter);
    if ((isNetworkConnected() == true)) {
        getData();
    } else {
        builder.setTitle("turn on internet");
        builder.setCancelable(false);
        builder.setPositiveButton("ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                dialog.dismiss();
            }

        });
        builder.create();
        builder.show();
    }

}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    if ((isNetworkConnected() == true)) {
        getData();
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    } else {
        builder.setTitle("turn on internet");
        builder.setCancelable(false);
        builder.setPositiveButton("ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                dialog.dismiss();
            }

        });
        builder.create();
        builder.show();
    }
}

public String loadJSONFromAsset() {
    String json = null;
    try {
        InputStream is = this.getAssets().open("data.json");
        int size = is.available();
        byte[] buffer = new byte[size];
        is.read(buffer);
        is.close();
        json = new String(buffer, "UTF-8");
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
    return json;
}

private void getData() {
    builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    try {
        JSONObject reader = new JSONObject(loadJSONFromAsset());
        JSONArray jArray = reader.getJSONArray("rootnode");
        for (int i = 0; i < jArray.length(); i++) {
            try {
                JSONObject jsonObject = jArray.getJSONObject(i);

                Movie movie = new Movie();
                movie.setTitle(jsonObject.getString("title"));
                movie.setRating(jsonObject.getDouble("rating"));
                movie.setYear(jsonObject.getInt("releaseYear"));
                movieList.add(movie);
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private boolean isNetworkConnected() {
    ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

    return cm.getActiveNetworkInfo() != null && cm.getActiveNetworkInfo().isConnected();
}
```

There should not be any duplicate data in my recycler view

```java
public class MovieAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MovieAdapter.ViewHolder> {
    private Context context;
    Movie movie;

    public MovieAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Movie> list) {
        this.context = context;
        this.list = list;
    }

    private ArrayList<Movie> list;


    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.single_item, parent, false);
        final ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder(v);
        viewHolder.view_container.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                // Intent i=new Intent(context,Main2Activity.class);
                //   String a=list.get(viewHolder.getAdapterPosition()).getTitle();
                //   Double b=list.get(viewHolder.getAdapterPosition()).getRating();
                //  int c=list.get(viewHolder.getAdapterPosition()).getYear();
                //  String g =String.valueOf(c);

                // viewHolder.textYear.setText(g);


                //   i.putExtra("movie",a);
                //   i.putExtra("rating",b);
                //   i.putExtra("year",c);
                //   context.startActivity(i);
            }
        });
        viewHolder.something.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Double w = list.get(viewHolder.getAdapterPosition()).getRating();
                String k = Double.toString(w);
                viewHolder.textRating.setText(k);
            }
        });
        return viewHolder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        movie = list.get(position);

        holder.textTitle.setText(movie.getTitle());
        holder.view_container.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                int c = list.get(holder.getAdapterPosition()).getYear();
                String g = String.valueOf(c);

                holder.textYear.setText(g);

            }
        });
        // holder.textRating.setText(String.valueOf(movie.getRating()));
        // holder.textYear.setText(String.valueOf(movie.getYear()));
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {

        return list.size();
    }


    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        TextView view_container;
        TextView something;
        public TextView textTitle, textRating, textYear;

        public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            view_container = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView5);
            something = itemView.findViewById(R.id.Rating);
            textTitle = itemView.findViewById(R.id.title);
            textRating = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
            textYear = itemView.findViewById(R.id.main_year);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: that's how RecyclerView is used - views are reused. And if the text has been set to TextView, you need to remove it if you don't need it on the other position.

Comment: it is better use POJO class to maintain itemview state. If not, recycler view will recycle your view and display wrong data.

Comment: It is strange that you are ot having duplicate data issue as you are calling `getData()` two times, On `onCreate` and on `onResume` too.

Comment: @DHAVALASODARIYA yes you are right i have the duplicate data and i removed it

Comment: You have to change your logic, as far as I understood it is not possible in the way you do, change your listener place from RecyclerView class to Application class, and try to handle click there.

Comment: @FerruxNebiyev How can i get data into my application(because i need to get the data based on the position)?? can you help me??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never bind data with view inside `onCreateViewHolder` method as you have done this on click of `something' ,`holder.textYear.setText(g);`

So instead of managing it like this, I suggest you to manage your rating textview with visibility.

Just move your click action inside `onBindViewHolder()`, and do below changes with it.

```
    Double w = list.get(viewHolder.getAdapterPosition()).getRating();
    String k = Double.toString(w);
    viewHolder.textRating.setText(k);

    viewHolder.textRating.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

    viewHolder.something.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            viewHolder.textRating.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    });
```

**To maintain the review state:**

First create one booelan variable inside your model class and generate getter-setter for that.

i.e.

```
private boolean isReviewedVisible = false;

public boolean isReviewedVisible() {
    return isReviewedVisible;
}

public void setIsReviewedVisible(boolean isVisible) {
    this.isReviewedVisible = isVisible;
}
```

Than add below checks in `onBindViewHolder()` method.

```
    if(movie.isReviewedVisible()){
       viewHolder.textRating.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    } else {
       viewHolder.textRating.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    }
    viewHolder.something.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            movie.setReviewedVisible(true);
            viewHolder.textRating.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    });
```

Comment: @DHAVALASHODARIYA it worked but when i scroll up and down the data is invisible any solution??

Comment: Then you need to manage state inside your model class. Let me update my code.

Comment: @dineshreddy I have updated my answer. Please review it.

Comment: @DHAVALASHODARIYA i am not getting any thing what should i mention in isReviewedVisible() method

Comment: @dineshreddy Ohh. Sorry. I forget to mention, you also need to generate getter-setter in that model class.

Comment: yes its correct but only the first click value is storing and the remaining clicks data is not displaying

Comment: May I know where you have initialised this variable `isReviewedVisible`?

Comment: i have initialised it in the Movie class not in my adapter or MainActivity